# Power BI Data Connection

Tags: powerbi-datasource

PowerBI Data Connection
How can I establish a secure live data connection to a data source in Power BI, to ensure data integrity for my project?

I want to establish a secure live connection to my data source. My data source is an Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

**Connect to Your Data Source:**

- Click on the "Home" tab in Power BI Desktop.
- Click on "Get Data."
- Choose "File" and then select "Excel" from the list of data source options.
  **Select Your Excel File:**
- Browse to and select your Excel file.
  **Configure Your Data Connection:**
- Power BI will open the Navigator window, displaying the tables and data in your Excel file. Select the tables you want to include in your data model and click "Load."
  **Choose Live Connection:**
- In Power BI, you have two primary options for data connectivity: "Import" and "DirectQuery." To establish a secure live connection, select "DirectQuery."
  **Configure Data Source Options:**
- You may be prompted to configure specific data source options for Excel, such as specifying credentials if the Excel file is password-protected.
  **Set up Data Security:**
- If your data source requires authentication or permissions, ensure you configure these settings to maintain data security. This might involve using Windows credentials, database credentials, or other forms of authentication based on your data source.